# Call asynchronous operations in RxJS operators

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

With the code below I get a value every 500ms and I take 10 of them.

Now I want to filter out invalid values but the function I want to call is asynchronous (but happens very quickly) and I don't know how to do that in the filter operator.

```
this.subscription = this.input.getStream()
    .throttleTime(500)
    .filter(value => {
      // I want to filter out invalid values
      // but the function I want to call here is async
    })
    .take(10)  // and get 10 valid ones
    .subscribe(value => {
      this.values.push(value)
    })
```

Note: I want the filter to happen *after* the time throttling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an "async" version of filter operator in RxJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490700/is-there-an-async-version-of-filter-operator-in-rxjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to:

1. use `flatMap` to call the async function, returning both the value and the result to be used for filtering;
2. filter based on the latter; then
3. at some later point, unwrap the value again.

In your case, maybe something like:

```ts
this.subscription = this.input.getStream()
    .throttleTime(500)
    .flatMap(value => asyncFunction(value).map(include => ({ value, include }))
    .filter(({ include }) => include)
    .take(10)
    .subscribe(({ value }) => {
      this.values.push(value)
    })
```